# git push changes to master, without overwriting work done by another person

Tags: git, push

Normally I push code up to 'master' branch by:

```
git add . 
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

Working perfect, everything stored up to date.

Now someone else has done work on 'master', from a different location.

How can I push my changes up to master, without overwriting his changes - leaving the code changes in his commit intact?

When I do my normal git push I get:

```
christophecompaq@ubuntu:~/Populisto$ git push
To git@github.com:Christophe1/Populisto.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Christophe1/Populisto.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
christophecompaq@ubuntu:~/Populisto$
```

If I use 'git push -f', won't that overwrite everything that he did?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you do a `git push` you have to do a `git pull`. Other person's work has to be merged with your code first and then you can push your changes to the repository. git pull will keep your updated code as it is and only add/update code (meaning that git will merge code) from the last commit (other person's code).

In case where both of the developers have worked on the same piece of code then git will show *conflicts* which have to be *resolved* first.

Comment: Probably a silly question but...when I do a git pull, it's not going to replace all my updated code on my pc with the old stuff on github? I mean the only things to change on my pc will be the stuff from the last commit - the changes the other person made?

Comment: No harm in asking basic questions. git pull will keep your updated code as it is and only add/update code (meaning that git will merge code) from the last commit (other person's code). Just in case you and the other person worked on same file (or same piece of code) then git will prompt a message that there are conflicts and merge cannot be completed successfully. Then you will have to resolve the conflicts and complete the merge process.

Comment: But if you have local un merged changes then git pull create  merge commit. So if you have your local commits which are not present on remote then try "git pull --rebase"

Comment: @AzizShaikh Hi, quick question please, i pushed my code to a new repo of github origin master. Now, i made changes to my code, should i push to origin master again with new commit or push to new branch? ( i usually just commit to master again)